# Visual Studio and Resharper showing error intermittently

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper-8.0

I see VS2012 and Resharper complaining about a method not found BUT if I clean the solution and build, it works. After sometime (especially during get latest from SVN) it again display same error. It seems visual studio loosing intellisense about few methods/property.

Someone please help to resolve this annoying behavior.

When method not found until project is clean and built:

[image: MethodNotFound]

When property is not found until project is clean and built:

[image: PropertyNotFound]

Comment: i also reached this problem .. .

Comment: Good to know I am not alone :)

Comment: happens to me from time to time. Restarting VS usually helps.